# Rails 3.2.8 - How to handle Time zones?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, datetime, timezone

I've participated the Rails Rumble this year and I found myself tangled by time zone issues.

I uploaded my app in linode and I live in EST time zone or -4 to UTC.

I have a model and it saves things by doing the following:

```
def self.processing_creation(user_id, home_id, chore_id)
  registered_chore = RegisteredChore.where("DATE(created_at) = ?", Date.today).find_by_user_id_and_home_id_and_chore_id(user_id, home_id, chore_id)
  unless registered_chore
    registered_chore = RegisteredChore.create(user_id: user_id, home_id: home_id, chore_id: chore_id, created_at: Time.zone.now)
    user = registered_chore.user
    user.add_one_chore_point
  end
  registered_chore
end
```

RegisteredChore.where("DATE(created_at) = ?", Date.today).find_by_user_id_and_home_id_and_chore_id(user_id, home_id, chore_id)

returns false even if the data was just created.

I noticed that "create" saves in UTC but Date.today uses user's local time zone.

What's the best way to handle this?

Another example to illustrate the issue:

1. I want to register a chore at 11 PM in EST time.
2. The server is already in the next day (e.g: 12).
3. Rails saves the data in the next day date (12).
4. But user is still in day 11.
5. Technically, user with the current method, could save the entry again because the days are different from the db and user interface.

How to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Rails will, by default, save times to the database as UTC. If you're using `DATE([Date.today])`, then it's going to be looking up records on the 11th, not the 12th. To get the right date, you probably want to set `Time.zone` to the user's current timezone, and then do the query.

I built a gem called [by_star](http://github.com/radar/by_star) to handle this kind of date searching, and I reckon you should use it. With it, your query would be this:

```
RegisteredChore.today.where(:user_id => user.id, 
                            :home_id => home.id,
                            :chore_id => chore.id)
```

Answer (score 1):

Rails 3 by default saves all the time in database relative in GMT+00:00 time zone. So you will have to set an offset while computing time depending on your timezone. Else, you can change default Activerecord time zone by adding following to `application.rb`

```
config.time_zone = 'Your time zone' (Example: 'Eastern Time (US & Canada)')
config.active_record.default_timezone = 'Your time zone' (Example: 'Eastern Time (US & Canada)')
```